# Run Windows Forms application as service?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-services

I have a Windows Forms application that I wrote that does some monitoring of an inbox and database. The customer has informed me that it needs to run every time the server reboots. Shame on me for letting the customer change the requirements.

I was thinking ... is there any way to make a Windows Forms application run as a service so that it starts automatically?

**Clarification**

I would like to try to not have to write any more code ... if possible!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This answer is obsolete, since the linked article was deleted in 2012. However, StackOverflow does not allow the accepted answer to be deleted. So, kindly do not downvote this answer, since I have informed you that it is obsolete.)

Alt link: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20111221041348/http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/xyntservice.aspx

C++ source (Or use the Browse Code tab on the article): https://web.archive.org/web/20111228050501/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/xyntservice.aspx

> Unfortunately, the Zip file source code download does not work within the alternative links.

### Start Your Windows Programs From An NT Service

Check this article out: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=719&av=49654

It's a really old article, but it has worked for 8 years and it continues to be kept up to date by the author.

It will do what you want to do.

Comment: I found something similar that comes with the Windows Resource Kit ...  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Comment: I think it is still important to test this because it may be that the GUI aspect of the application may falter when it is launched if a user is not logged in to the server.  In any previous scenarios I have had like this, the administrators would set up auto-login scripts and simply launch the exe.

Comment: Note: I acknowledge that this is a hack, but that is what MattRuma is looking for in this case.

Comment: How did this end up at 1 vote again? I voted it up to 2 a couple hours ago and I can't see any reason to down vote it.

Comment: The linked article is no longer available.

Comment: You still can find the article on WayBack machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20111228050501/http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/xyntservice.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the Zip file source code download does not work on the WayBack machine link, but the source file CPP can be browsed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure the application can run unattended safely (by this I mean it can ***never*** throw up a modal UI element like a Message Box) and it doesn't need any interaction until shutdown, where it will simply be terminated, then run it as a scheduled task with the trigger set to system start up.

If it can run unattended but it may need to be shutdown and restarted manually or it can't just be terminated at shutdown then use the XYNTService as recommended by [EnocNRoll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463073/run-windows-forms-application-as-service#463117). It's a horrible hack but it will work for what you want.

But by far the best solution is to separate the functionality of your program from the User Interface and write a proper service. And for a production server I wouldn't allow anything else. If it isn't easy to separate then you have some design issues you should look into anyway.

Comment: I've assumed here that MattRuma is simply looking for a quick way to make this happen.  Otherwise, I totally agree.  However, the battle to do things the right way is hardly ever won after something is in production.

Comment: Yes ... I am looking for the quick and dirty ... I don't have the luxury or time to do this right ... at least not right now.

Comment: Yeah, I know how that feels. Just use XYNTService or the Task Scheduler then but really check your app very carefully for any possible unattended UI problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a winforms application as a service, you just won't be able to see it-- it will be displayed on a so-called virtual desktop, which can't be viewed on your monitor.

Comment: This is what I am looking to do.

Comment: ok, cool, then there are no worries about launching a UI Thread without a logon context?  great!  Then either of the two articles posted thus far should work, theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/), a commercial application that will run any application as a Windows Service. It is similar to XYNTService (mentioned by EnocNRoll), but has more features and is fully supported.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to even consider this is to make sure that the application has no UI elements to it, as you have to jump through hoops on a non-Vista machine to make this work, and on Vista, you can't interact with the desktop at all.

Rather, you would be best off refactoring out the functionality into a set of shared libraries, and then create a service that uses those libraries, and install that at the client.

Comment: Hmmm ... so there is no way to go into Windows Services and make it run my application like a service?

Comment: Nop, a service require a class derived from ServiceBase class and a ServiceInstaller class to install in Windows Services.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nice decoupled functionality in you forms application, it should be straightforward to create a service class with its installer and then launch your processor class in the OnStart method of the service:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
                    Processor processor = new Processor();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(processor.OnStart);
        workerThread.IsBackground = true;

        try
        {
            workerThread.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
                      //...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InstallUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(VS.80).aspx) to install your app as a service, but you need to make sure it's not reliant on the GUI, and I would recommend you change the startup of the app so it doesn't attempt to create any forms.

Comment: To use InstallUtil you need a class derived from Installer, you also need a ServiceProcessInstaller() and ServiceInstaller() objects defined in your installer class. InstallUtil looks for these in your exe project.

Comment: Maybe it's not InstallUtil I'm thinking of then.. I've definately installed a "normal" app as a service several times using a command line util. SC rings a bell.